# displaying flv-video attachment in post

Tags: posts, videos

i've attached a local .flv video to my post (it was uploaded and is inside my mediapool).
my question: how can i display it inside my post? (the video player)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .flv is not a video player in itself, rather just a video file to be played in one.

To display it, you'll need to play it from an actual video player. Unlike .wmv and .mp4, .flv files won't play natively in your browser without one.

There's a couple [great](http://videojs.com/) open source [options](http://flowplayer.org/) out there.

There are also [a few](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hana-flv-player/) [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flv-embed/) that might already have the functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at:

- [Post video players, slideshow albums,
  photo galleries and music / podcast
  playlist](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-playlist-and-gallery-plugin/)

Its a plugin that will take care of all your media needs including an flv player

(long name for a plugin).